# Erro: TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factorys

Estou chamando um serviço da amazon e está dando problema, segue código:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'emails', function($scope, emails) {
emails.success(function(data) {
    $scope.email = data;
});
console.log($scope.email); }]);
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('emails', ['$http', function($http) { 
return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/emails-api/emails.json')
.success(function(data) { 
    return data; 
}) 
.error(function(err) { 
    return err; 
}); }]);
```

No console aparece:

> TypeError: $http.get(...).success is not a function

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `success` do `$http.get` só é funcional até a versão `1.4.3` do `AngularJS`. Para as versões subsequentes, utilize o método `then` para capturar o resultado da promessa.

Substituindo no seu código:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'emails', function($scope, emails) {
  emails.then(function(data) {
      $scope.email = data;
      console.log($scope.email);
  });
}]);
```

E na `factory`:

```
app.factory('emails', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/emails-api/emails.json');
}]);
```

Comment: Obrigada Sorack :)

Answer (score 1):

O método `get` do `$http` retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), segue abaixo a maneira correta para fazer a chamada.

> Controller

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'emails', function($scope, emails) {
  emails.then(function(data) {
      $scope.email = data;
      console.log($scope.email);
  });

}]);
```

> Factory

```
app.factory('emails', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/emails-api/emails.json').then(function(data) { 
        return data;
    }, function (error) {
        return error;
    }); 
}]);
```

Comment: Desta maneira também deu certo, obrigada Hiago. :)

Comment: ;) disponha Rafaela